Disable template checks 'is not a known element'
I am trying to disable template checks in Angular 14.  I have a large project and am refactoring into modules.  As I am doing this I am getting a ton of template errors for components that I have not refactored, this makes it hard to setup and check my new modules.
Looking to suppress 'is not a known element' errors.
I have tried turning off all strict mode options:
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": false,
    "strictInputTypes": false,
    "strictAttributeTypes": false,
    "strictOutputEventTypes": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,

As well as using:
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],

Still seeing template checks/errors.  Is it possible to turn off these errors/checks?  If so any ideas on where I am going wrong?
